# How to delete large amount of relationships in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have created a large amount of relationships (millions) that I want to delete with a Cypher request.

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate('MATCH (a:CAR)-[r:REL_NAME]->() DELETE r','', {batchSize:50000})
```

Is it the right syntax ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the documentation](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/periodic-execution/), I think the call should rather be like this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('MATCH (:CAR)-[r:REL_NAME]->() RETURN r', 'DELETE r', {batchSize:50000})
```

The first statement is run in batch and produces relationships.
The second statement is applied to every produced relationship.

Note: labels usually follow the PascalCase convention (`CAR` should be `Car`).